# Is it possible to change the colors in a built-in Angular2 component, like <material-progress>?

Tags: angular, angular-dart

...if so, how would I do it? I'm using AngularDart. I want to change the colors of the primary and secondary progress bars.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 3):

In current published version it is not perfect. You can override the style in your component using something like:

```
.my-progress-bar /deep/ {
  .progress-container.indeterminate {
    background-color: $indeterminate-color;
  }
  .progress-container.indeterminate > .secondary-progress {
    background-color: $active-color;
  }
  .active-progress {
    background-color: $active-color;
  }
  .secondary-progress {
    background-color: $secondary-color;
  }
}
```

By replacing the `$foo-colors` with values you want. In a future update we will provide a mixin that will allow you to just pass the colors.